# tcl/tk creating/modifying a widget in a different thread

Tags: multithreading, tcl, tk-toolkit

What i'm trying to do is modify or create a widget created in the main thread from a different thread, I read that tk is not safe thread and I haven't been able to accomplish this. I just want to exhaust my options when trying to do this. When I try to create a widget for example:

```
set threadID [thread::create {

    label .test -text "hello" 

    thread::wait
}]
```

and I also try this:

```
label .test -text ""        
set threadID [thread::create]
thread::send $threadID [list .test configure -text "HEllo World"]
```

This gives me an error saying that the command label is invalid, so is there any way to create/modify a widget from a different thread?

Comment: Does not work. No way.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible. If you need to access/modify widgets from different threads, I suggest the following approach:

- Use a single GUI Thread. Pass the Thread Id to all necessary threads.
- Use `thread::send` to send the read/write commands to the GUI thread (maybe in blocking mode).

You have to decide yourself when you have to use the `-async` flag.

Thread safe toolkits are rare (if such a thing is possible), for example Java's Swing is not thread-safe. The usual approach there is to post messages to the event queue that are handled in the AWT-Thread (e.g. with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`), like here.

Answer (score 1):

Every widget is tied strongly to a single interpreter, and every interpreter is tied strongly to a single thread; what you want won't work.

The simplest workaround is to put commands in the other thread that delegate to the GUI thread to do the tinkering with the widget:

```
pack [label .l]
thread::send $threadID "
    proc .l args {
        thread::send [thread::current] \[list .l {*}\$args\]
    }
"
```

After that, the other thread can use:

```
.l configure -text "Hello, World!"
```

and it will work. Well, mostly. (The `-textvariable` option won't go across threads without quite a bit of extra magic with traces, and images are also interpreter-bound.) You also won't be able to adjust the geometry management of the widget without more work, but that's less-frequently an issue.

The other approach is to embed a toplevel with `-use` in a frame with `-container`, but that's not an option I've had the greatest of success with. Still, it's supposed to work across processes (well, on Unix/X11 anyway) so it might also work with threads.

Comment: can you elaborate more on the top level approach..? can you show me a simple example, thanks

Comment: I'd use `interp alias` for such things.

Comment: And I used `-use` for really crazy things with twapi. (like replacing some parts of the original GUI)